# How to get All Group Users from Active Directory LDAP Server in Springboot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to retrieve all groups and respective users from Active Directory LDAP servers.

Can anyone please help with sample code?

Answer (score 2):

```
package test;

import java.util.List;

import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPConnection;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPSearchException;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchRequest;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchResult;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchResultEntry;
import com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.SearchScope;

public class Test2 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            List<SearchResultEntry> usersFromLdap = getUsersFromLdap();
            System.out.println(usersFromLdap);
        } catch (LDAPException e) {
            //TODO handle exception
        }

    }

    public static List<SearchResultEntry> getUsersFromLdap() throws LDAPException, LDAPSearchException{
        String searchBaseDN = "dc=your-domain,dc=com"; //your-domain.com
        String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sn=*))"; //see e.g. https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-write-ldap-search-filters-792496933.html


        LDAPConnection connection = new LDAPConnection("host.your-domain.com", 389);
        try {
            connection.bind("yourLdapUser", "YourLdapPassword");
            SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(searchBaseDN, SearchScope.SUB, searchFilter);
            request.setSizeLimit(0);
            SearchResult searchResult = connection.search(request);

            List<SearchResultEntry> result = searchResult.getSearchEntries();
            return result;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: We don't have any user credentials as we are using active directory. Please help me on this. thanks @heiwil

Comment: We created a user in our LDAP to be able to login by code to fetch user informations. So you can create a user like `yourApplicationUser` and use this credentials to login. You should be able to login with every existing user, if the settings allow it.

Comment: so it will give all users from all groups in active directory? thanks @@heiwil

Comment: It returns all entries of objectClass=user. The searchFilter could be set individually. See e.g. https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-write-ldap-search-filters-792496933.html

Comment: when trying with above code, getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.unboundid.ldap.sdk.LDAPException. Please help me thanks. @heiwil

Comment: I use com.unboundid.unboundid-ldapsdk:3.2.1. So include this jar in your project: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.unboundid/unboundid-ldapsdk/3.2.1

Comment: Is it working, if you delete the LDAPException? Try it without the try/catch block in main, and delete the import of LDAPException.

Comment: Thanks a million! After spending almost a week and struggling with MSFT Azure LDAP this sample finally get it work.